# How to count items present in WPF datagrid and display it in another page?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, observablecollection

I am working in a C# WPF application using MVVM model. I have a DataGrid in which I am adding multiple values and I want to count the number of items present in the grid and display that value in another page. The issue is that the count is displaying on the same page where I have my DataGrid but it is not displaying the count on the other page.

My code is as follows :

```
public ObservableCollection<VLANSPropertyClass> vlan { get; set; }   

<TextBlock Margin="3,0"  
           Style="{StaticResource SummaryValues}"  
           Text="{Binding vlan.Count}"
          />
```

How can I display the DataGrid's item count on a different page?

Comment: Have this two page a same DataContext?

Comment: Coudn't you simply have the same ViewModel for both pages !

Comment: So if you want this expression working in two page, Two page must be refer to same DataContext.

Comment: @RezaArabQaeni Sorry DataContext is same !!

Comment: If the two pages have the same DataContext, then have you checked that your `vlan` property actually has data in it when viewed from your second view?

Comment: Are you sure that the 2 pages are using the same INSTANCE of the DataContext (Model)?

Answer (score 0):

Make your ViewModel a single instance.  ie.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private static ViewModel instance = new ViewModel();

    private ViewModel()
    {

    }

    public static ViewModel Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
                instance = new ViewModel();
            return instance;
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> vlan { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can, in your first window, set DataContext to ViewModel.Instance, ie.

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = ViewModel.Instance;
        ViewModel.Instance.vlan=new ObservableCollection<string> { "Fred", "Theo", "Lil Kitty" };
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ViewModel.Instance.vlan.Add(String.Format("String {0}", ViewModel.Instance.vlan.Count + 1));

        Window1 win = new Window1();
        win.Show();
    }
```

Then you could have another window that also sets the DataContext to the ViewModel.Instance, ie:

```
public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = ViewModel.Instance;
    }
```

This will allow you to have both windows set to the SAME instance of the ViewModel, and you can still bind like this in each window (My example creates a new window each time and updates the count in all windows etc):

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding vlan.Count}" />
```